# Vlan did't work?

Tags: centos, vlan

I have 2 host, connected via switch.
There is no vlan configured on the switch.

On Host A :

```
5: enp5s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:58:ef:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.11/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global enp5s0f1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.10.10/24 scope global secondary enp5s0f1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:fe58:ef95/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[root@ceph-node1 ~]# ip addr show enp5s0f1.1001
24: enp5s0f1.1001@enp5s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:58:ef:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.0.1/24 scope global enp5s0f1.1001
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:fe58:ef95/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

On Host B :

```
5: enp5s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:59:a9:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.12/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global enp5s0f1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:fe59:a95b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[root@ceph-node2 ~]# ip addr show enp5s0f1.1001
8: enp5s0f1.1001@enp5s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:59:a9:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.0.2/24 scope global enp5s0f1.1001
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:fe59:a95b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Host A ping Host B on non-vlan interface :

```
[root@ceph-node1 ~]# ping 192.168.10.12
PING 192.168.10.12 (192.168.10.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.10.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.169 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.12: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.241 m
```

s

But when A ping host B on VLAN interface

```
[root@ceph-node1 ~]# ping 172.16.0.2
PING 172.16.0.2 (172.16.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.16.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.16.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

OS is Centos7

Kindly please give me clue to fix this problem

Sincerely

Comment: I'd run `tcpdump -eni enp5s0f1` on host A while pinging from host B to see what traffic reaches host A. Perhaps also do the same in parallel on host B, maybe the switch is dropping packets with the 802.1Q tag set? Can you try it with a straight ethernet cable between host A and B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switches drop tagged packets if they not belong to the vlans which configured on the switch port.

So, if you use vlans on servers, you may setup vlans on switches.

Also look at this [question/answers](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19618/how-does-switch-treat-ingress-tagged-packet)